Texture artifacts - only in perspective mode
How do, I have recently started noticing some artifacts on my textures in the viewport while using Blender. I think this is since I moved to 4.1, but definitely 4.2, as that is what I am using now.
I had a good play about and noticed that clicking the Raytracing box helps and improves it, but does not eliminate it.
Whilst looking up the issue I found a really old post on a different forum about z-bias and z-fighting. I didn't think this was the answer as there were no duplicate faces. However in the midst of the answers was one that casually suggested it was a orthographic/perspective issue. They didn't go into any detail but I switched to orthographic and it immediately cleared.
Anybody explain this issue, if there is a way to fix it and what is different in last couple of Blender releases.
Thanks in advance.
Ste


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

@Jakemoyo
Part of the mesh showing this issue is available in this file here StarLord Edit.
Cheers Ste

Yeah, I'm not getting that effect on my end. Might be a bug in 4.2. Are your GPU drivers up to date? Have you checked the recent bug reports in the Blender github for issues similar to this?

Thanks for checking. I have checked my GPU, all up to date. I can't see anything on the github, but I will keep looking and widen my search as well.
It's just strange that it only does this in perspective mode on my machine? What changes, regarding the texture displayed, by swapping to this view?
Anyway, thanks for having a look.

You could try using a Solidify modifier, to give it a little thickness. The fact that it's a single plane might be causing issues.

@Jakemoyom sorry for the late reply here. I have been away.
All parts of the object are solid, I sell this item for 3D Printing. The model is sound. It seems to be just a viewport issue.
